# Why telegram group automatically becomes super group?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

My telegram bot is a member of several groups. I use it to send different kind of incident notifications to different telegram groups. Today i noticed couple of my telegram groups automatically became super group. Thus their chat id changed. So my message sending was failed. By the time i found out that the chat id has changed a lot of notifications were missed.

This messages are fired automatically. So if the chat id changes automatically then it is a problem for me.

I have couple of questions to understand the cause.

1. Why telegram groups becomes supergroups ?
2. How many ways chat id of a chat in telegram can change ?
3. Does telegram channel's chat id can be changed ? (If no then i will stop using groups. I will use channel)

I have browsed google and telegram bot api documentations. But i could not find my answers.

I know if a group chat is migrated to super group then upon sending the next message with the old chat id, i will get a response from telegram with the new chat id. Then i can update the chat id. But i want to avoid this way of updating the chat id. I would like my group chat id to remain same forever.

Answer (score 8):

The answer can be found [here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/5593).

- making the group public
- changing a user's permissions
- changing an admin's permissions
- changing group history visibility
- the 201st member joins

will convert the group to supergroup automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. Telegram updated their groups with their update from [22/01/19](https://telegram.org/blog/permissions-groups-undo). Maybe this caused the Id change

> As of today, supergroups and basic groups are simply groups. It now
>   takes just a few taps to make any group public, add admins with
>   granular privileges or toggle persistent history.

2. I do not think the chat Id will change again (if there isn't a breaking change like the last update)
3. **All Id's can be changed eventually.** It depends on Telegram. But as I said it is really unlikely that Id's change that often neither for groups nor for channels.